# Large Excel File - Alternate solution to receive inputs from multiple users at the same time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I manage a huge 50 mb Ms-Excel model which has input, calculations and output/report sheets (total 63 tabs and macros).

Since the model is huge, the users are unable to open the file and feed their inputs at the same time. Users would like to feed inputs and refresh the calculations to monitor their respective product report sheets and then save it.

Because of this, we have to maintain a time table for product owners to feed the file one after another. This delays the entire process.

Can anyone please suggest an alternate solution to receive the input from the users and update the file at the same time?

Kindly let me know if you need any other details.

Thanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

There would need to be more details to describe the environment you are working in to get a specific answer. To get to a more specific answer, there would have to be a description of what the macros are doing, how the outputs use the inputs and where the workbook is stored and used.

In all cases, it seems that you need to split the analytics from the inputs.  With the description you have provided, I would think that among the myriad approaches (with some presumed constraints based on your description), you could use Power BI to split the input content from the output results.  I can give a crude example that is based on a lot of assumptions:

1. Each Product Owner would have a personal input workbook.
2. They would save their own personal workbook that would contain their inputs using a common and uniform structure in a common place:

   - Put them in a common OneDrive folder (there is also a Box API, but more complex to implement)
   - Put them in a common Sharepoint directory
3. Build a separate and common PowerBI based analytics output **§** that all product owners can open and refresh that reads all of the inputs from the common directory or folder using the built-in Power Query capabilities.

   - shape the inputs and combine them into a set of common tables that the analytics computations can use
   - the Power BI analytics can be opened simultaneously by many users who can refresh it to get the most up-to-date view that includes the content from their colleagues.
4. Each time a product owner makes an update, they must save it and refresh the analytics to see the results. Until it is saved, none of their colleagues will see the update either.

§ - depending on the analytics you are performing, this can be done in Power BI Desktop or Excel for Windows or Excel mounted in Sharepoint.

Note that step 3 can also be added to each individual workbook from the product owners, so that they could receive the analytics output from their own personal workbook. The analytics engine would use Power Query to read in the latest results from their colleagues.

But my suspicion is that what I described above would be a terrible user experience because the Power BI would be constantly applying the ETL with each refresh. Without knowing more about the environment, what the macros are doing, and how the analytics working, it is hard to suggest a really good solution.  I suspect that your answer could be found in Sharepoint or Azure Data Factory or a CI/CD tool.